# Sqlite3 Python: can't use "limit" as column name

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

There are 6 columns and for some reason when my program gets to this bit of code during install, it simply creates a blank file with no table.

Through trial and error, I found the only thing that did not create a blank file was removing the limit row.

I have other code that runs and looks the same just for different databases and it works fine.

```
        try:
            # Connect to Database
            conn = sqlite3.connect('databases/Categories.db')
            cur = conn.cursor()

            # Create Table
            cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE categories (
                priority text,
                name text,
                type text,
                increment text,
                total real,
                limit real)""")

            # Commit and Close
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
        except sqlite3.OperationalError:
            pass
```

Comment: any error codes?

Comment: Nope, nothing. It just creates an empty database file with no symbols or anything. If it helps, I'm using pycharm

Comment: try saying `print('Done')` at the end of ur `cur.execute(..)` and see if it gets printed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"limit" is an SQL [keyword](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html), for example, as in

```sql
SELECT foo 
  FROM bar
  LIMIT 10;
```

If you want to use "limit" as a column name in sqlite, it needs to be quoted, in one of these ways:

- 'limit'
- "limit"
- [limit]
- `limit`

So for example, your statement could be

```
        cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE categories (
            priority text,
            name text,
            type text,
            increment text,
            total real,
            "limit" real)""")
```

Note that it must be quoted in other statements too, for example

```
"""INSERT INTO categories ("limit") VALUES (?);"""
```

Comment: That did it, I was thinking it was some kind of conflict and thought I was going to have to rename the column. Now I don't have to. :)

Answer (score 0):

I did some more testing and I fixed it by renaming the limit row to something else. Turns out, sqlite3 doesn't like rows named limit.

Comment: As a matter of fact, it's a syntax error to do so. `limit` is a reserved keyword in SQL (https://docs.actian.com/psql/psqlv13/index.html#page/sqlref/sqlkword.htm). You could have also observed the behavior by making the `except` block more verbose and you'd have discovered that there was always an error.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I actually removed the Try/Except phrase and replaced CREATE TABLE with CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS statement that I just learned about. :D